# Plane isometries $g\ , f$ , properties of fixed points and types

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given two plane isometries $g\ , f$  and $f^{'} = g\circ f \circ g^{-1}$ prove that:

- If $P$ is a fixed point of $f$ then $g\left(P\right)$ is a fixed point of $f^{'}$ and if $Q$ is a fixed point of $f^{'}$ then then $g^{-1}\left(Q\right)$ is a fixed point of $f$.
- Prove that $f$ and $f^{'}$ are isometries of the same type (e.g if $f$ is a rotation isometry then so is $f^{'}$)

**My attempt:** 
I've tried evaluating $f^{'}$ at $A$ and substituting it for the explicit expression but with no luck.

I've proven that $f^{'}$ is an isometry and that topological orientation is preserved iff $f$ preserves topological orientation.

And I know that if some isometry $h$ preserves topological orientation it has to be one of the following:

- Identity
- Rotation
- Translation

And that if $h$ has a fixed point it has to be :

- Identity
- Rotation

But I could not quite formulate a proof using all this data.

**NOTE:** This is my first university level course and I'm 14 so I don't have much experience neither with mathematics related resources over the net or with rigorous proofs, so sorry if something is not according to SE policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints (in order of the questions asked):

For $P$ a fixed point of $f$, $g(f(g^{-1}(g(P))))=$?

Assuming $Q$ is a fixed point of $f'$ amounts to saying that $Q=g(f(g^{-1}(Q)))$. Apply $g^{-1}$ to both sides and examine what you have.

$g(Id(g^{-1}(x)))=$? (The $Id$ denotes the identity transformation.)

The very first pair of questions help you decide that $f$ and $f'$ either both have a fixed point, or both do not have a fixed point. This will help you decide the statement for rotations and translations.

Comment: Really, most of these just fall out from writing down the question in symbols.